# Why windows executables show incorrect compiler timestamps?

Tags: windows, compile, sysinternals

I have observed that windows executable files show incorrect timestamps when I view them in PE studio.
[For example this Notepad.exe file shows a compiler timestamp of **0x86FCBD69 (Mon Oct 07 03:45:05 2041**
)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtVps.png)

To validate this today (3 May 2021),I converted a Python program file to EXE & checked the same in PE Studio. It also showed an incorrect compiler timestamp of **0x5FFEC122 (Wed Jan 13 15:15:06 2021**
) [Python executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LL0z.png)

Why are compiler timestamps incorrect ? To my understanding if the Python program was converted to exe today, it should show today's date under the compiler timestamp.

Comment: I'm thinking that's the date the compiler itself was built, not the executable you're looking at.

Comment: @MetalMikester - The compiler is from the future?  What’s more likely is the program is improperly converting the date.

Comment: @Ramhound LOL! I wasn't focusing on the year, just the name "compiler-stamp" which I seem to recall is the compiler build date, not the EXE build date. But I'm not 100% sure. The second one is Jan 2021, however.

Comment: @MetalMikester - In either case it’s the wrong date, which indicates, the software is converting the value improperly.  I also wouldn’t except either field to contain worth whole data based on their name

Comment: @Ramhound Skynet is planning to go operational in 2041? Interesting

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They're deliberately set to a fixed value:

- The Old New Thing: [Why are the module timestamps in Windows 10 so nonsensical?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180103-00/?p=97705)

  > One of the changes to the Windows engineering system begun in Windows 10 is the move toward *reproducible builds*. This means that if you start with the exact same source code, then you should finish with the exact same binary code.
  >
  > […]
  >
  > Timestamps are another source of non-determinism. Even if all the inputs are identical, the outputs will still be different because of the timestamps. [...] Setting the timestamp to be a hash of the resulting binary preserves reproducibility.
- The Old New Thing: [What does the executable timestamp really mean?](http://web.archive.org/web/20110715002523if_/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/13/10185815.aspx)

  > The name *timestamp* is misleading. Its real purpose is to act as a signature so that the operating system can determine whether a DLL against which one set of values was precalculated matches the DLL physically on the system. A better name for it would have been "UniqueId".

Note: There are two meanings to the term 'signature' here. Raymond calls the field a "signature" only in the sense of it being something unique that allows distinguishing this binary from other binaries (in the same way that the 'MZ' bytes are a signature for all .exe files). It is however not a *cryptographic* digital signature and does nothing to ensure the file's integrity or authenticity.

Comment: Well that's quite informative. I believe these signatures are used to ensure the integrity DLL files so that no malicious adversary can modify & recompile them.

Comment: They are not signatures. You're correct that signatures are used to ensure integrity and prevent tampering, and Microsoft indeed digitally sign all their executables -- **but timestamps are not the same thing as signatures.** The timestamp is a 32-bit number; even if it _were_ used to prevent tampering, it takes literally minutes to simply run through every possible 32-bit number until you find one that "passes". Actual signatures are hundreds of bits (or thousands because Microsoft uses RSA).

Comment: @supercat - Microsoft made this change awhile ago, it’s not like they recently made the change, it’s been more than 4 years.

Comment: @Ramhound 4 years lol, those articles are from 2010-11

Comment: @HongOoi - Only one is from 2011